# Get width of parent element in Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to implement a component named CamViewMatrix in Vue.js. My requirement is to get the width of CamViewMatrix's parent inside itself (say in `created()` method of CamViewMatrix) so that I can make some calculations with it (there are some time-based charts that need to be made responsive which is not possible unless an initial value for width is in hand).

```js
<div>
  <div class='controller-wrapper'>
    ...
  </div>
  <CamViewMatrix v-bind:cameras='cams' />
</div>
```

---

I tried assigning an `id` to its parent and passed the same as a prop to CamViewMatrix, and attempts to `getElementById`, but it's not able to. Code given below:

```js
<div id='parentid'>
  <div class='controller-wrapper'>
    ...
  </div>
  <CamViewMatrix v-bind:cameras='cams' parentId='parentid' />
</div>
```

And inside CamViewMatrix component:

```js
<script>
export default {
  name: 'CamViewMatrix',
  props: {
    parentId: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    ...
  },
  created() {
    console.log(document.getElementById(this.parentId)); // ️ logs null
    ...
  }
}
```

With the above code, I am not able to get the parent element (it's logging `null`).

---

Have also tried using `ref` and `$parent`, but was not able to. Kindly help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ditch passing it, `console.log(this.$parent.$el.scrollWidth)` will work

Comment: `document.parentid.offsetWidth` will work in your case (unless you have more than one element with the id of `parentid` in your document, in which case it will always return the width of the first element in DOM with that `id`). However, it would be the **wrong way** to go about it. The proper way is to use a template ref and pass it down via props to the child component (or make it available to the child via an external store). Ideally you shouldn't pass the ref, but only the value of the prop you're interested in.

Comment: Side note: `parentid` is sub-par naming. It will get you in trouble pretty fast. Consider changing it to something more descriptive of the role/function performed by the element in the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`created()` is the wrong lifecycle hook to do that.

If you check the lifecycle diagram from the docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram

The element stuff is not yet done (rendered) and only the instance is created.

You most likely what to do that in `mounted`.

Next, you can access your component's parent via `this.$parent` and the element via `this.$parent.$el`.

Check out: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Instance-Properties

---

If you want a specific element from parent, create a ref and access it like:

`this.$parent.$refs.refNameYouAdded`

If it's a Vue component, then it'd be a Vue instance so you need to access `$el` again:

`this.$parent.$refs.refNameYouAdded.$el`

otherwise if it's a HTML element, then no need to do that.

---

most of the time, the above answers work but sometimes if your parent component does things like moving elements somewhere else then it might not be accurate.

as mentioned in the comment, you can still access the correct parent element by doing:

`this.$el.parentElement`

Comment: I would go for `this.$el.parentElement` instead. `$parent.$el` will give you the element that holds the parent **Component** not the parent **HTMLElement**